# Cambiar Color Background de un JLabel pulsando un JButton desde otra ventana

Tags: java

Me gustaria saber como cambiar el color de fondo (setBackground) de un JLabel pulsado un boton desde otra ventana.

(JLabel en clase Ventana1)

```
lblLuzC = new JLabel("");
lblLuzC.setOpaque(true);
lblLuzC.setBackground(Color.RED);
lblLuzC.setBounds(204, 224, 16, 16);
contentPane.add(lblLuzC);
```

(JButton en clase Ventana2)

```
btnColor = new JButton("Cambiar color");
btnColor.setBounds(144, 85, 95, 23);
contentPane.add(btnColor);
btnColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

});
```

Comment: Hola JHG, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Deberías de colocar algo de tu código.

Comment: @FrEqDe ahi tienes. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que puedes hacer es crear un objeto de la clase Ventana1:

`Ventana1 objetoVentana1 = new Ventana1();`

Para que así puedas acceder a los métodos y propiedades de esa clase.

Después en la acción del botón, en el `ActionListener()`, quedaría una cosa así:

```
btnColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       objetoVentana1.lblLuzC.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
});
```

Me he dado cuenta que al nombre de tu botón al ponerle el `ActionListener()` le has puesto 2 veces btn, seguro que ha sido un fallo a la hora de copiar. Saludos

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, muchas gracias Mario

Comment: Te funcionó? @JHG

Comment: He tenido que hacer un metodo get para acceder al JLabel y despues del setBackground un setVisible;       objeto.getlblLuzC().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
objeto.setVisible(true);

Comment: Ah vale, perfecto :)

Answer (score 1):

Generar getter del JLabel (ventana1).
Acceder al JLabel en ventana2 mediante el dicho metodo.

```
   btnColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          objetoVentana1.getLblLuzC.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          objetoVentana1.setVisible(true);

   });
```